# Display the time in table view by selecting the time from picker

Tags: iphone

I am making an iphone app, in which I wanna to implement the time picker. The time which i select from time picker must be displayed in table view. So how should I connect the time picker and table view to get the output.

Please give me answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"d MMM yyyy";
```

You can do it in the `UITableview` delegate like this.....

```
cell.textLabel.text=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

where datePicker is the `UIDatePicker`... 
You can also have the dateFormatter as a global variable if u want.....
Hope this helps.
Happy coding :)